# Coordinates, determine the point of origin or points of origin.

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, algorithms, analytic-geometry

I have coordinates, determine the point of origin or points of origin, based on the coordinates I have.
There is some formula, I do not know that it is based on the probability to determine the points the fires.
An example of a map, to understand how the points are distant and close to each other.
https://www.mapcustomizer.com/map/coordinate